# Android Studio > VCS > Local History > Put Label. Что это такое Put Label?

Tags: android, android-studio, контроль-версий

Android Studio > VCS > Local History > **Put Label**

Что это такое **Put Label**?

Нажимал, вводил значение, но не заметил на что это повлияло...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понял, этой функцией вы помечаете текущее состояние кода в локальной истории. Локальная история не зависит от систем контроля версий. Затем, если вы сделаете изменения, и захотите вернуться к какому-то конкретному состоянию, вы можете использовать эту пометку.
[Документация JetBrains по Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html).